# Replacement of one macro within other macro in c++

Tags: c++, macros

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

#define DEFAULT 100
#define ADD(A,B) "A is : " + A + "Default is : " + DEFAULT + "B is : " + B

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string A = "a";
    string B = "b";

    cout << ADD(A,B) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I want output of this to be `A is : a Default is : 100 B is : b`.

But when I compile this program it gives me compilation error.

Comment: I'm guessing that error is fairly informative. Do try to post the **exact** error message when posting a question. Saying "...it gives me compilation error" is only slightly more informative than "it don't work."

Comment: `#define DEFAULT "100"` or `std::to_string(DEFAULT)` should help.

Comment: BTW, you don't need macro here, a function is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add strings and ints. But with C++11, you can convert that int to a string with `std::to_string(100)`. i.e.:

```
#define ADD(A,B) "A is : " + A + "Default is : " + std::to_string(DEFAULT) + "B is : " + B
```

Also, for future reference, always be sure to include the exact error message (copied and pasted from the compiler output).

And one last thing: don't include `<string.h>`. Instead, just include `<string>`. `<string.h>` is the C string header (whose C++ twin is `<cstring>`), and that header doesn't have `std::string` or many of the other features you're probably after.

Comment: Shouldn't the first string in the summation be an `std::string`? E.g., using `std::string("A is : ")` instead of `"A is : "`.

Comment: @UndefinedPavel: That's not necessary, because `A` is a `std::string`.

Comment: Thanks a lot that solved my problem. And next time I would remember for exact error messages.

Comment: You don't need to use `std::string` at all; the preprocessor `#` operator will turn an integer literal into a string literal.

Answer (score 2):

i am not sure what u are trying to do. But 100 u cant add to a string. Define it as a string.

```
   #define DEFAULT "100"
   #define ADD(A,B) "A is : " + A +"Default is:" +DEFAULT+ " B is : " + B

   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
       string A = "a";
       string B = "b";

       cout << ADD(A,B) << endl;

       return 0;
  }
```